# Valgrind Error "Invalid write of size 4" C

Tags: c, valgrind

I'm programming in C, and when I use Valgrind to check memory errors, the next error has shown:

```
==9756== Invalid write of size 4
==9756==    at 0x40164D: main (flowTracker.c:294)
==9756==  Address 0x24 is not stack'd, malloc'd or (recently) free'd
```

The line 294 of flowTracker.c is the next:

```
tabla_hash[clave_hash]->contador++;
```

And the declaration of tabla_hash is:

```c
#define TAMANHO_TABLA 1048576

typedef struct{

    int tiempo_ini;
    int tiempo_ult;
    uint8_t quintupla[13];
    int num_bytes;
    int num_SYN;
    int num_ACK;
    int contador;
    double pack_s;
    double bits_s;
} FlujoIP;

FlujoIP *tabla_hash[TAMANHO_TABLA];
```

Comment: Where do you populate the array?

Comment: At first, all variables of the array are empty

Comment: There is no such thing as "empty" in C++, do you mean that you never explicitly set their value?  In which case, that explains the error you're seeing.

Comment: Add the allocations part of your code.

Comment: [valgrind](http://www.valgrind.org) needs the source code to determine where the problem happened, why od you think humans don't?

Comment: if I write " tabla_hash_clave[clave_hash]->contador = 0; " before the line 294, valgrind show me that the error is in the new line.

Comment: Yes, because you've haven't initialised table_hash_clave[clave_hash].

Comment: `0x24` is a very suspicious address which could be `contador`'s offset. `tabla_hash[clave_hash]` is probably a null pointer, for which you should check before accessing it.

Comment: `tabla_hash[clave_hash]` is `NULL`

Comment: `FlujoIP *tabla_hash[TAMANHO_TABLA];` declares `table_hash` as an array of pointers which will all be initially 0 (`NULL`) if this declaration is not in a procedure (or unpredictable if it is). If that is what you want, you will need, as @Oliver points out, to initialise `tabla_hash[clave_hash]` before your first access to it, e.g. with `if( t_h[c_h] == NULL ) t_h[c_h] = malloc(sizeof(*t_h[c_h]));`.

Comment: @PJTraill, not so.  C makes no guarantees about the initial value of an object for which no initializer is provided.  In particular, the elements of the OP's `tabla_hash` are not guaranteed to initially be 0 / NULL, and in fact Valgrind shows that the one he is accessing is *not* NULL (though it almost certainly *is* invalid).

Comment: @JohnBollinger: K&R 2.4 Declarations ‘External and static variables are initialized to zero byt default.’ [C99](http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG14/www/docs/n1256.pdf), 6.7.8 Initialization **Semantics** 10 says the same. I did say _‘if ... not in a procedure’_! Moreover, as argued above by M Oehm, the 0x24 = 6*24 is probably the offset of `contador`, which also supports it being `NULL`.

Comment: @JohnBollinger I suggest reacquainting yourself with how objects declared to have static storage duration (such as those declared outside of functions, and those declared using the `extern` keyword) are initialised.

Comment: @PJTraill, *mea culpa*.  I think I was confusing static duration with static linkage, and even then my wrong claim was broader than I intended.  However, I suspect that I was also influenced by the fact that the pointer value actually observed by the OP (`0x24`) was *not* the result of an initialization to zero.  I was looking to agree in a general sense with the failure-to-initialize proposition, but it now appears that doesn't fly.

Comment: @JohnBollinger: No problem! (But I would argue that `0x24` _is_ a result of initialisation to 0 – and addition of the member offset.)

Answer (score 3):

As [4566976](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4566976/4566976) pointed out, `tabla_hash[clave_hash]` is (*probably*) `NULL`. That's just a guess, as you haven't provided an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which reproduces the issue without us having to fill in the blanks or fix compiler errors...

It seems to me as though you probably meant to declare `tablahash` like so: `FlujoIP tabla_hash[TAMANHO_TABLA];` (though, wow! That's a *huge* array)... and you should then be able to change `->` to `.` like so: `tabla_hash[clave_hash].contador++;`

Alternatively, if you were to precede the offending statement with `if (tablahash[clave_hash] == NULL) { tablahash[clave_hash] = malloc(sizeof tablahash[clave_hash][0]); }` or something, that might also be appropriate... Don't forget to `free` all of the items within your *huge* array.

Comment: Why the clumsy conditional expression, rather than a simple `if`? (But +1 anyway.) Also, M Oehm’s explanation is appreciably more convincing than 4566976’s bald assertion.

Comment: @PJTraill What's so clumsy about it? How is "a simple `if`" actually simpler? Didn't you notice how similar the two are?

Comment: You’re right that it’s actually not a huge amount simpler, but at least `tabla_hash[clave_hash]` only occurs 3 times instead of 4! It’s not that I don’t like conditional expressions, but I’m not so keen on using them to do nothing in one case!